# Python3 access previously created object

Tags: python-3.x

Im new to programming in general and I need some help for accessing a previously created instance of Class. I did some search on SO but I could not find anything... Maybe it's just because I should not try to do that.

```
for s in servers:
    c = rconprotocol.Rcon(s[0], s[2],s[1])
    t = threading.Thread(target=c.connect)
    t.start()
    c.messengers(allmessages, 10)
```

Now, what can I do if I want to call a function on "c" ? 
Thanks, Hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating several different objects that you briefly name `c` as you go through the loop. If you want to be able to access more than the last of them, you'll need to save them somewhere that won't be overwritten. Probably the best approach is to use a list to hold the successive values, but depending on your specific needs another data structure might make sense too (for instance, using a dictionary you could look up each value by a specific key).

Here's a trivial adjustment to your current code that will save the `c` values in a list:

```
c_list = []
for s in servers:
    c = rconprotocol.Rcon(s[0], s[2],s[1])
    t = threading.Thread(target=c.connect)
    t.start()
    c.messengers(allmessages, 10)
    c_list.append(c)
```

Later you can access any of the `c` values with `c_list[index]`, or by iterating with `for c in c_list`.

A slightly more Pythonic version might use a list comprehension rather than `append` to create the list (this also shows what a loop over `c_list` later one might look like):

```
c_list = [rconprotocol.Rcon(s[0], s[2],s[1]) for s in servers]
for c in c_list:
    t = threading.Thread(target=c.connect)
    t.start()
    c.messengers(allmessages, 10)
```